# Wie sagt man ' What happens if...' auf Deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german

How do you say ' what happens if...' ?

1. Was wird, wenn ich ins Kino gehe, ohne meine Mutter um Erlaubnis zu bitten?

Is it colloquial or standard german?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would translate "what happens if" as *Was passiert, wenn...* or *Was geschieht, wenn...*, and more colloquially as *Was gibt's, wenn...*, or even *Was, wenn...*

It's okay to say *Was wird, wenn...*, which strikes me as colloquial.

Comment: vielleicht ist es hier sinnvoller präsens zu verwenden: *"was ist, wenn"*

Comment: Stimmt. "Was ist, wenn" klingt besser als "Was wird, wenn"; ich bin mit nur nicht sicher bzgl. der Zeitform. Ich denke mal Präsens, wenn man eine logische Folgerung betont und/oder die Konsequenz bekannt ist und Futur I, um die Konsequenz als solche hervorzuheben und/oder wenn man über dieselbe spekuliert. Macht das Sinn?

Comment: Muttersprachler... bitte solche Fragen nicht stellen, da muss ich über intuitives Tun nachdenken ;) Im generellen würde ich Futur I für diese konstruktion nicht verwenden, denn hier geht es nicht um Spekulation. falls das der Fall wäre, verwendete ich Futur I. zur spekulation empfähle ich Konjunktiv (subjunctive)